# Install solr-tomcat5.5 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, tomcat

How can I install `solr-tomcat5.5` on Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to run following command from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat5.5-webapps tomcat5.5-admin tomcat5.5
```

For more details follow this guides:

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-tomcat-in-ubuntu/

http://yoodey.com/install-solr-141-ubuntu-1010-maven-maverick-multicore-using-tomcat-6-complete-guide

Comment: I need to install tomcat 5.5 As I stated in the question.

Comment: Then change 6 version to 5.5, in example: sudo apt-get install tomcat5.5-webapps

Comment: I need to install solr integrated with tomcat not just tomcat

Comment: You can follow the second link, there is a full guide how to do that.